# Getting element by a custom attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have an XHTML page where each HTML element has a unique custom attribute, like this:

```
<div class="logo" tokenid="14"></div>
```

I need a way to find this element by ID, similar to `document.getElementById()`, but instead of using a general ID, I want to search for the element using my custom `"tokenid"` attribute. Something like this:

```
document.getElementByTokenId('14');
```

Is that possible? If yes - any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is not good to use custom attributes in the HTML. If any, you should use [HTML5's `data` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Nevertheless you can write your own function that traverses the tree, but that will be **quite slow** compared to `getElementById` because you cannot make use of any index:

```
function getElementByAttribute(attr, value, root) {
    root = root || document.body;
    if(root.hasAttribute(attr) && root.getAttribute(attr) == value) {
        return root;
    }
    var children = root.children, 
        element;
    for(var i = children.length; i--; ) {
        element = getElementByAttribute(attr, value, children[i]);
        if(element) {
            return element;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the worst case, this will traverse the whole tree. Think about how to change your concept so that you can make use browser functions as much as possible.

In newer browsers you use of the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) method, where it would just be:

```
var element = document.querySelector('[tokenid="14"]');
```

This will be much faster too.

---

**Update:** Please note @Andy E's comment below. It might be that you run into problems with IE (as always ;)). If you do a lot of element retrieval of this kind, you really should consider using a JavaScript library such as jQuery, as the others mentioned. It hides all these browser differences.

Comment: +1 for the hard work, but bear in mind that `children` has a <IE9 quirk where it returns comment nodes and was only added to Firefox in version 3.5.  `childNodes` with a `nodeType` check would be a "safer" approach.  Also, `hasAttribute()` isn't supported by IE7 and lower.  For those browsers, you'd have to do something like `root.attributes.getNamedItem(attr).specified`.

Comment: @Andy: Uh, I did not know about these issues... thanks! I will leave it as exercise for the reader though ;)

Comment: var element = document.querySelector('[tokenid="14"]');
--- not in safari 5.1.4

Comment: @Andrei: Mmmh, according to http://caniuse.com/ it should be supported. Have you tried `document.querySelector('[tokenid=14]')` (value without quotation marks)?

Comment: How is this done with Angular? `ng-bind` is custom too

Answer (score 56):

```
<div data-automation="something">
</div>

document.querySelector("div[data-automation]")
```

=> finds the div

```
document.querySelector("div[data-automation='something']")
```

=> finds the div with a value

Answer (score 6):

If you're using jQuery, you can use some of their selector magic to do something like this:

```
    $('div[tokenid=14]')
```

as your selector.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this with vanilla JavaScript will do the trick:

```
  const something = document.querySelectorAll('[data-something]')
```

Comment: When adding an answer to a nine year old question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: Well it's just a summary of some of the answers It's just the way I like to do it Thanks anyway for the comment

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with JQuery:

```
$('[tokenid=14]')
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lar9y/)'s a fiddle for an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com), then:

```
var myElement = $('div[tokenid="14"]').get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this more stable Function:

```
function getElementsByAttribute(attr, value) {
  var match = [];
  /* Get the droids we are looking for*/
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  /* Loop through all elements */
  for (var ii = 0, ln = elements.length; ii < ln; ii++) {
    if (elements[ii].nodeType === 1){      
      if (elements[ii].name != null){        
      /* If a value was passed, make sure it matches the elements */
        if (value) {
          if (elements[ii].getAttribute(attr) === value) 
           match.push(elements[ii]);           
      } else {
        /* Else, simply push it */
         match.push(elements[ii]);          
      }
     }
   }
  }
return match;
};
```