# trouble with a function for changing dates Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByAttribute'

Tags: javascript, date, getelementbyid

I try to change the dates in javascript.

So to start, in fact I have a mysql query that selects records from the database.

These records have two dates a date called action and another for validation.

In fact the script is supposed to change the dates on criteria but only if the validation date is equal   to 0000-00-00 that is that the registration of the database is not considered valid.

So I actually added all the fields are not validated attribute required.

and I tried the code below I struggled to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lz(x){
return x.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/,'0$1')
}

    function addday() {
        var items = new Array();
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker hasDatepicker");


            items[0] = document.getElementById("date" + (1)).value;


            items[1] = document.getElementById("date" + (2)).value;


            items[2] = document.getElementById("date" + (3)).value;


            items[3] = document.getElementById("date" + (4)).value;


            items[4] = document.getElementById("date" + (5)).value;


            items[5] = document.getElementById("date" + (6)).value;


            items[6] = document.getElementById("date" + (7)).value;


            items[7] = document.getElementById("date" + (8)).value;


            items[8] = document.getElementById("date" + (9)).value;


            items[9] = document.getElementById("date" + (10)).value;



        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementByAttribute('required').value;
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByAttribute'
            var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
             var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10)+ +nb);
            nb=document.getElementById('nb').value;

                itemCount[i].value = lz(itemDt.getDate())+"-"+lz(itemDt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+itemDt.getFullYear()
        }


       return items;
           }

</script>
```

but I return the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #  Has No method 'getElementByAttribute'

I do not understand why.

the code that generates the javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lz(x){
return x.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/,'0$1')
}

    function addday() {
        var items = new Array();
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker hasDatepicker");

  <?php  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE n_doss='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['n_doss'])."' AND qualite='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['qualite'])."' AND liasse='".$_GET['liasse']."' AND `date_validation`='0000-00-00' ORDER BY `date_action` ASC" ;
  $rules2=mysql_query($sql2) ; $i2=0;
  while($data2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rules2)) {?>

            items[<?php echo $i2 ; ?>] = document.getElementById("date" + (<?php echo ++$i2 ; ?>)).value;

<?php }?>


        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementByAttribute('required').value;
            var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
             var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10)+ +nb);
            nb=document.getElementById('nb').value;

                itemCount[i].value = lz(itemDt.getDate())+"-"+lz(itemDt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+itemDt.getFullYear()
        }


       return items;
           }

</script>
```

I use this micro form to execute the function

```
<input type="button" value="( - )" width="22" height="22" onClick="subday()" />
                  <input name="jours" type="text" value="" size="5" id="nb" />
                  <input type="button" value="( + )" width="22" height="22" onClick="addday()"  />
```

Receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind regards.

SP.

Comment: That is because there is no such thing.  Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267816/getting-element-by-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript

Comment: Dear Sir thank you verry much for your quick reply. Actualy I haver severa fields that have the criteria required like this one: for example: <input type="text" name="data[5][date]" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="date5" value="01-10-2012" size="12" style="background-color:#FF0" required="">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as getElementByAttribute unless you make your own

XUL has a 
[getElementsByAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Method/getElementsByAttribute) but not available to normal JS AFAIK

Perhaps you wanted to do this?

```
function addday() {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker hasDatepicker");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].getAttribute('required')) {
      var itemDtParts = items[i].value.split("-");
      var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10)+ +nb);
      items[i].value = lz(itemDt.getDate())+"-"+lz(itemDt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+itemDt.getFullYear()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Sir thank you verry much for your quick reply. I've tried using the code you gave me, but it does not change anything. I added a return items; at the end