# Javascript get Element in LI tag

Tags: javascript

I got a `li` that looks like:

```
<li temp="true">HELLO</li>
```

How would I get "temp" so I can manipulate "HELLO" in JS...I know how by id or even className

Comment: What have you tried so far? And are you aware that this is _not_ valid HTML?

Comment: You should use `data` attributes for this purpose. `data-temp = "true"`. Then use `getAttribute` or the `data` DOM interface to retrieve the value.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267816/getting-element-by-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript

Comment: Can you show the container and rest of elements in it?

Comment: @IrvinDominin  Thanks for that link....querySelector worked...thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In supporting browsers (that is, anything except ancient IE):

```
var li = document.querySelector("li[temp=true]");
```

If support for older IE is required try this:

```
var li = document.querySelector ? document.querySelector("li[temp=true]")
  : (function() {
      var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'), l = lis.length, i;
      for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
          if( lis[i].getAttribute("temp") == "true") return lis[i];
      }
      return false;
  })();
```

Comment: It's a fantastic feature that makes about 99% of all jQuery use completely obsolete, much to my satisfaction! IE8 supports it, which means that the only people who don't have access to it are those who have adamantly decided to disable Windows Update (of which my opinion is to sod them right back). Also, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get a list of matching nodes, and you can even replace `document` with the node of your choice to only search that subtree.

Comment: @Kolink Come now, do you really prefer writing all that code to writing `$('li[temp=true]')`? How does this "obsolete" jQuery when it does exactly what jQuery does?

Comment: @Asad Hell yes. I want to be able to blame myself and fix things when the code breaks, not spend hours guessing at it. I write my own framework with the exact tools I need, rather than just grabbing a sledgehammer for everything.

Comment: @Kolink So you are using a framework, just an alternative to jQuery. That doesn't make it obsolete, since in general you're using the same tools to accomplish the same task (Sizzle uses querySelector et al too). The difference is one of authorship.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use the attribute selector:

```
$('li[temp="true"]');
```

Alternatively, you can use the `document.querySelectorAll()` method for a native JS solution. You should be aware of the cross-browser implications of this, however:

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('li[temp="true"]');
```

You can see a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b43Pe/) of the above.

As an aside, you should use `data-` attributes to store custom attributes with HTML elements, for example the correct syntax should be:

```
<li data-temp="true">HELLO</li>
```

Comment: Cannot see the `jQuery` tag on the question.

Comment: But guys, didn't you know? [jQuery is the answer to everything!](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: @Kolink I actually laughed aloud. +1

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all li.

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var found;
for(var i=0; i< li.length;i++){

    if(li[i].getAttribute("temp") == "true"){
       found = li[i]; break;
   }
}

console.log(found);
```

OR 
You can use native query

```
var found= document.querySelectorAll('li[temp="true"]');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvkgF/)