# How to get the id of an input type using attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a check box like

```
<input id="inp__str_Object__17" type="checkbox" name="inp__str_Object__17" sym_name="Cust_attr_1" value="400024" >
```

Using javascript how  can i get the id (inp__str_Object__17) using  sym_name="Cust_attr_1"

Like `document.getAttribute("SYM_NAME")`

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267816/getting-element-by-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector

Answer (score 1):

```
var myInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var index in myInputs) {
   var myInput = myInputs[index].getAttribute('syn_name');
   if (myInput === 'some value')
      return myInputs[index].id;
}
```

Hope this was helpfull

Comment: you should to warp this code into `function` .. or assign id `var id;` and `break;` on condition match . other wise it throw error `SyntaxError: return not in function`

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to wrap this code with a function :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a native solution exists to retrieve an element by a custom attribute.  You can do some of this work yourself such as:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var id = "";
for(var x = 0; x < elem.length; x++){
    if(elem[x].getAttribute("sym_name")){
       id = elem[x].id
    }
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/WvaYx/1/

Or you could pull by the `name` attribute:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByName("inp__str_Object__17");
var id = elem[0].id;
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/WvaYx/

Comment: I want id by attribute name ie sym_name

Comment: @Warrior Updated but I'm not sure if you will like the answer.  I don't think there is a native way to retreive elements by a custom attribute.

Comment: How i can loop through the iput types with id starting with 'inp__strObjectType__'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the kind of methods that do a "query by attribute" as described here [Get elements by attribute when querySelectorAll is not available without using libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector) to get the input ; then, just get the "id" attribute.