# Take an element from DOM with not a common attribute

Tags: javascript

if we have this:

```
<div class="test">
```

we use this DOM to call it.

```
div.test
```

but if we have a custom attribute like this

```
<div xpl-highlight="">
```

how can we call it from DOM

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting element by a custom attribute using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267816/getting-element-by-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select it like this: `div[xpl-highlight]`

Answer (score 0):

Same as you would do with css selector

```
document.querySelector('[xpl-highlight]')
```