# How to search element by class and retreive title attribute in Javascript (greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'd like to select this element:

```
<span class="score likes" title="22">22 points</span>
```

such as: var likes = comment.getElementsByTagName('score likes').title;

and then return the value of "title" tag.

I've found lots of posts on how to select element by class or title, but I haven't been able to find how to select element by class and then get the value of title to save to a variable. This is for a grease-monkey script.

Edit: This is NOT a duplicate question, does anyone ever read the question before flagging for duplicate questions?  To be extra clear, I do NOT want to search by the TITLE tag, I want to GET the value of the title tag and save it to a variable. I do not know what the value of the title tag is before searching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting element by a custom attribute using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267816/getting-element-by-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript)

Comment: Did you mean `getElementsByClassName('score likes')`?

Comment: Also `[0]` since it's an array: `comment.getElementsByClassName('score likes')[0].title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking some liberties for your original selection method (`getElementsByTagName` => `querySelector`) , you can access your element's attributes using [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
var likes = comment.querySelector('.score.likes').getAttribute('title');
```